# Stored Procedure with multiple parameters hangs

Tags: sql, forms, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure that has 2 parameters.  When I run the SP in SQL it returns values as expected.
When I call the SP in my ASP page(Not asp.net) it hangs.
I have another SP that only takes one parameter and when I call this one from my ASP page it works as expected.
This is the code I am using to call the SP with 2 parameters:
MID = Request.Form("MID")
        CardNoString = Request.Form("FullCardNo")

```
    set connUBC3=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    connUBC3.Open "UBC" 
    If Err.number &lt;&gt; 0 then
        TrapError Err.source &amp; ": " &amp; Err.description
    End If

    set cmdTranByCardNo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    With cmdTranByCardNo
        .ActiveConnection = connUBC3
        .CommandText = "BlahBlah_Transaction_GetByMerchantIdAndCardNo"
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter ("RETURN_VALUE", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter ("@MerchantID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, MID)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter ("@CardNo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, CardNoString)
        set SearchTranByCardNoRS = .Execute

        If Err.number &lt;&gt; 0 then
            TrapError Err.source &amp; ": " &amp; Err.description
        End If
    End With
```

this is the ASP call for the single parameter SP that works:

```
set connUBC3=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  connUBC3.Open "UBC" If Err.number &lt;&gt; 0 then TrapError Err.source &amp; ": " &amp; Err.description End If
cmdFindTrans2 = "BlahBlah_Transaction_GetLast10ByMerchantId '" &amp; MID &amp; "'"   set SearchTranByCardNoRS = connUBC3.Execute(cmdFindTrans2)  If Err.number &lt;&gt; 0 then TrapError Err.source &amp; ": " &amp; Err.description End If
```

I have also tried the multiple parameter SP without the Returnvalue line.
Any idea

Comment: Looks like a merchant services application :) Anyways, what values are you passing?  I don't see an example of the exact values.  The problem could lie with what you're passing and how SQL is expecting it with the SP.

Comment: I am sending to strings of numbers one for each parameter and when I run them in sql (same Data) it returns the expected results. I have another SP that does exactly the same thing (meaning it hangs when called from the page but works in SQL) and I have a stored Proc as noted ubove that works fine.

Comment: Which part was the solution? Was it the `Execute` or the `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set SearchTranByCardNoRS = Something.Execute` There's no command to execute here.

```
cmd.Parameters(1) = x1
cmd.Parameters(2) = x2 
cmd.Parameters(3) = x3
cmd.Execute
```

Also, I would verify that you're not passing any `NULLS` to SQL through the script. That may trip it up as well.

Comment: You should ask it in comment to the question so the OP is notified.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Thanks - Still semi-new to answering questions :)

Comment: Sure, such things are not trivial - took me long months to figure. :-)